# Dynamic Proxy in Java EL

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, javabeans, el

**EDIT: I narrowed down the problem and posted the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847458/google-app-engine-jetty-introspection-fails-for-dynamic-proxy). Please check it out!**

I am trying to use dynamic proxies to make HTML form processing easier. I am using a pretty plain MVC setup (no fancy frameworks) using JSPs on Google App Engine. I keep getting the following exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find property testValue in class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.toBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:430)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:290)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:231)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    ...
```

Okay, so here is the code. First, the interface I am proxying:

```
public interface MyForm {
      public String getTestValue();
}
```

Next, the code that creates the proxy:

```
// imports omitted

public final class Forms {

    private Forms() { }

    public static <T> T fromRequest(
            final Class<T> klass,
            final HttpServletRequest request) {

        Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                klass.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[]{ klass },
                new InvocationHandler() {
                    @Override public Object invoke(
                            Object proxy,
                            Method method,
                            Object[] args) throws Throwable {

                        return "Will this be returned?";
                    }
                });
        return (T)proxy;
    }
}
```

Next the "action" class:

```
// imports omitted

public class MyAction extends Action {

    // Called by the controller, which forwards to the returned JSP
    public String perform(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        final MyForm form = Forms.fromRequest(MyForm.class, request);
        request.setAttribute("form", form);
        return "view.jsp";
    }
}
```

Finally, the JSP:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>${ form.testValue }</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm not actually doing any form processing yet. First, I just want to implement a proof of concept with the dynamic proxy. As mentioned, the code above does not work. However, perplexingly, if I make the request attribute an anonymous class that simply forwards to the proxy, it does work! So the following change fixes it:

```
request.setAttribute("form", new MyForm() {
    @Override getTestValue() { return form.getTestValue(); }
});
```

However, having to anonymously subclass the interface kind of defeats the purpose of the proxy. Could someone please tell me what's going on?

Comment: What's the `Action` class? Where's the controller? You say to use a plain MVC setup but I haven't seen any Servlet at all.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The MVC setup has only a single Servlet implementation, which is the controller. In the `web.xml`, all patterns go to the contorller servlet. It maintains a `Map<String,Action>` to delegate each URL to a specific `Action` subclass, then calls the `perform()` method and forwards to the JSP specified by the return value. This is a very simple MVC. I don't think the controller should affect this problem though -- I am just curious why the EL does not work for the `Proxy`, but then works for an anonymous class having the same interface.

Comment: I tried to create a proxy like you in a main method and discover its properties with Introspector (which is used by BeanELResolver), and it worked.

Comment: @WilQu Thanks for the feedback. I was also able to inspect properties with `Introspector`, but that is in the servlet. I am still puzzled why it appears to suddenly not resolve correctly in the EL, especially considering it works for the anonymous implementation. I'm assuming `BeanELResolver` makes some call to `getMethod()`? The `Proxy` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) is clear that invoking `getMethods()` on the proxy class should behave "as expected". Maybe I don't understand how the resolver works, or how `Introspector` works?

Comment: I think it is a problem with Jetty or GAE. I posted a refined question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847458/google-app-engine-jetty-introspection-fails-for-dynamic-proxy).