# Google App Engine/Jetty: Introspection Fails for Dynamic Proxy?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, jakarta-ee, jetty

Why does `Introspector` not correctly discover the properties of a dynamic proxy class in Jetty/GAE?

I ran into this curious problem while trying to use a dynamic proxy with Java EL/JSPs when deploying locally on GAE with Jetty. You can see the original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825474/dynamic-proxy-in-java-el).

Anyways, I have since simplified the code and narrowed down the problem. Here is the new code:

*MyServlet.java*:

```
package test;

// imports omitted

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public interface MyInterface {
        public String getValue();
    }

    private static <T> T getProxy(Class<T> c) {
        return (T)Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                klass.getClassLoader(),
                new Class<?>[]{ klass },
                new InvocationHandler() {
                    @Override public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m,
                            Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }

    public static void testIntrospection() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            MyInterface proxy = getProxy(MyInterface.class);
            BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(proxy.getClass());
            for (PropertyDescriptor d : info.getPropertyDescriptors())
                sb.append(d.getName()).append(", ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError("failed", e);
        }
        throw new AssertionError("found: " + sb.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        testIntrospection();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        testIntrospection();
    }
}
```

When I deploy the code above and send a GET request, I get the following:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: found: class,
```

However, I expected that both `class` and `value` would be discovered, as per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) for Proxy. But, when I just run it in `main()`, I get the expected output. I also tried putting the proxied interface in a separate file/package, and it did not work. To make things weirder, I also get the expected output when I change `MyInterface` to be private, protected, or default.

Why have I limited the question to GAE/Jetty? Because I was able to deploy the *exact* same servlet on Tomcat 7 with no problem, even when `MyInterface` is public.

In case it's relevant, I am using the Google plugin in Eclipse Juno, and I am only deploying locally.

One last thing: I checked the output of `proxy.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()` and it *did* include `getValue`. However, I can't simply parse the bean properties myself, because I need it to work in EL, which relies on `Introspector`.

I am really stumped by this one, so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: curious what you see if you replace the proxy with an anonymous inner class, maybe the Introspector just doesn't pick up on the value property regardless of the fact you're using a dynamic proxy?

Comment: @JamesOB It does work if I replace the proxy with an anonymous subclass that just forwards to the proxy. See my [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825474/dynamic-proxy-in-java-el) for a code example.